# Can moderators see deleted answers and act on them?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I would like to know if moderators can see deleted answer by a user?
Moreover, if I want that a moderator deletes my deleted answer, can he do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, moderators see everything that has been deleted, whether by other moderators or by users.

Once something has been deleted there is no action available for further deletion.  It can only be un-deleted.